# good practice to use "$" and run a function in one line in R

Tags: r, function

Today i have seem a "strange" thing and am wondering if this is a good practice. Basically there is a list:

```
testList <- list("columnA" = c(1, 2, 3), 
                 "columnB" = c(11,22,33))
```

and then a function:

```
calculateMean <- function(input){
  
  out <- lapply(input, mean)
  return(out)
  
}
```

and the this:

```
resultTest <- calculateMean(testList)$columnA
```

**Question:** Is this a good practice to refer to functions result without storing the results of a function in an intermediate step?

Comment: This question is very opinion-based. Let me play the Devil's advocate: if you were to store the intermediate results, what benefits are you getting for your particular application? Typically, you don't want to recalculate stuff over and over, but also don't want to use up too much memory by keeping variables you don't need. The question then is: will you ever need the other results?

Comment: But more importantly, the function definition/call isn't good practice. If you know in advance that you only need one column, why calculate the result on all of them?  Either limit the input, or pass an identifier down to the function to subset the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `sapply` and return a named vector and store it as a single vector and use that for other cases i.e. suppose we want to take the `max` of that vector, it can be applied directly instead of `unlist` the `list`.

```
calculateMean <- function(input){
  
  out <- sapply(input, mean)
  return(out)
  
}
```

-ouptut

```
calculateMean(testList)
columnA columnB 
      2      22
```

---

Regarding storing the output, it depends i.e. if we want to extract the output of 'columnB', we may need to run it again and do `$`.  Instead, save it as a single object and extract as needed

Comment: Could you explain the reasoning for using `sapply` over `lapply`? Otherwise your code isn't different from the OP's, with no explanation for why one is any improvement

Comment: lapply returns a list and sapply returns a named vector

Answer (score 1):

You ask if this is good practice.  I'd say there are good and bad aspects to it.

On the positive side, it keeps your code simpler than if you defined a new variable to hold `calculateMean(testList)` when all you are interested in is one element of it.  In some cases (probably not yours though) that could save a lot of memory:  that variable might hold a lot of stuff that is of no interest, and it takes up space.

On the negative side, it makes your code harder to debug.  Keeping expressions simple makes it easier to see when and why things aren't working.   Each line of

```
 temp <- calculateMean(testList)
 resultTest <- temp$columnA
```

is simpler than the one line

```
resultTest <- calculateMean(testList)$columnA
```

In some situations you could use an informative name in the two-line version to partially document what you had in mind here (not `temp`!), making your code easier to understand.

If you were trying to single step through the calculation in a debugger, it would be more confusing, because you'd jump from the `calculateMean` source to the source for `$` (or more likely, to the final result, since that's a primitive function).

Since the one-line version is relatively simple in your case, I'd probably use it, but in other situations I might split it into two lines.